# Translation doubts (が, き...)

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate some Japanese text I found to English (I'm very beginner, and self-learning).
There are two columns of Japanese; on the left:

私

い

日

本

が

and on the right:

大

子

き

で

す

I divided these columns into blocks, as follow:

私い = I (with Hiragana い used to strengthen the "I")

日本 = Japan

が = and

大 = large

子 = child

き = ki

です = copula ("is")

So, I'd translate it something like "I'm Japanese, and a large child is the ki", but I'm not sure this is the correct translation.
For example, what does き "ki" exactly mean? Does it mean spiritual energy? And, if so, why it is not written this way 気 ?

And is it correct to consider が as "and"? I found on an online dictionary that が can indicate sentence subject (so would Japan be the subject in this case? If so, how to reconstruct the phrase?)

Comment: The full sentence being `私い日本が大子きです。`? Are you sure it isn't `私は日本が大好きです。`?

Comment: As @Jeemusu says, please double check the い following 私 in the first line. It should be は (ha, but pronounced as wa here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the commenters above have mentioned, the sentence is likely

> 私**は**日本が大好きです (Watashi wa Nihon ga dai-suki desu)

If this is indeed what it was, `好き` ("suki") means "to like" (very loosely).  The kanji `好` means "good", "likeable", etc., and the accompanying `き` is [okurigana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okurigana) for the whole word `すき`.  I won't go into the details of okurigana here since that link explains it pretty well.

In Japanese, to say "like X", the pattern is `Xが好き`.  In this case, the `が` is a subject marker.  Often, `が` indicates a specific thing/example; what I like to refer to as a "specifier".  So in the pattern `Xが好き`, "X" is the thing specified as being liked.

As for `大好き` ("dai-suki"), as you noted, the kanji `大` means "large"/"big"/"great".  So `大好き` means to really like/love (not romantic love) something a lot.

So broken down, the sentence is

> 私は (As for me) 日本 (Japan) が (is what) 大好き (I really like)です。　→　"I really like Japan!" or "I love Japan!"

Hope this helps!